# C++ class output and sort

Tags: c++, class, sorting

I have a class student with parameters Number, Name, Grade  and  i have functions for input and output

```
  void insertdata(){
        cin>>number;
        cin>>name;
        cin>>grade;
    }
    void showdata() {
        cout<<number<<" "<<name<<" "<<grade<<endl;
    }
```

In the main function I'm inserting the data by this way

```
int n,i;
cin>>n;
student a;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    a.insertdata();
    a.showdata();
}
```

For example the progrom shows this

```
1 John 5
1 John 5
2 Ron 6
2 Ron 6
```

I want the input and output to be separate and sorted by grade:
Input:

```
1 John 5
2 Ron 6
```

Output:

```
2 Ron 6
1 John 5
```

For the sorting i'm using this

```
bool operator()(student const & a, student const & b) {
        return a.success < b.success;
    }
```

If someone can help I will be grateful
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: And in what kind of container your Student are going ?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include a simple but complete example? Also known as a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a predicate to pass to `std:sort`. For example:

```
bool by_grade_decr(student const & a, student const & b) {
    return a.grade > b.grade;
}

#include <algorithm> // for std::sort
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<student> students = ....;
  std::sort(students.begin(), students.end(), by_grade_decr);
}
```

Comment: std::vector<student> students;
    std::sort(students.begin(), students.end(), by_grade); Says that students it's not a type

Comment: @user3104718 that doesn't make sense. You must have an error or a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use the STL. Vector for the storage and the sort algorithm.

```
int n,i;
cin>>n;
vector<Student> storage;
student a;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    a.insertdata();
    a.showdata();
    storage.push_back(a);
}

sort(storage.begin(), storage.end());
```